# How to make a set of levels for my iOS game

Tags: ios, objective-c

So I have these 5 setter methods that set up this game I'm making with positions for my objects to be placed.  They are:

```
    - (void) setToInitialStateMain {
         [super clearBoard];
         [super setCellState:StoneOne forColumn:1 andRow:1];
         [super setCellState:StoneTwo forColumn:2 andRow:3];
    }
```

And 4 other setters like that.  So let's say I have 50 levels, and positions for all objects per level ready to be implemented into those 5 setters, how would I be able to do this, if at all?

How can I make it so that I press a number 1-50 on a screen, and my program will know that I pressed level 32, so load positions for level 32 (to be applied in those setter methods when they are called at the beginning stage of loading)?

Comment: What are you using, tableview or collectionview ? I think you are using collection view.
Why you dont use delegate "(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath" to do function you want ?

Comment: Neither, these positions that I put in (0-4) get fed through my state setters/getters, then accessed when initialized to display the image positions.  Then from there I take over manually and interact with the game.  How does the Collection view work?

Comment: Do you want to make a list button that user can choose level ?
If yes, please read UICollectionView.

Comment: Yes.  And, just to be clear, those 'setCellState:" methods (once I initialize the images) will display a stone at [1,1] and another stone at [2,3]...plus my other images.  This UICollectionView, upon your suggestion, will allow me to make the levels by implementing all sorts of image positions, correct?